# how to format the specified string as bold and set size in testcomplete using VB scripting language inj testcomplete

Tags: vbscript, testcomplete

I am trying to set the format for a particular string as bold and font size and colorindex.i am using VB script in testcomplete tool.can you please suggest me which method is used for that

```
sub sample
mystring="welcome to testcomplete"
aqstring.format(mystring)=Bold
mystring.Font.ColorIndex=10
mystring.Font.size=14

end sub
```

here i am getting vb script run time error..please help me which method i have to use..give some examples

Answer (score 2):

Well for it to add parameters on top of the string, the string needs to be attached to an object, for example, a log parameter below. A log parameter can support font styles because it is an object that does have more properties than text and length(like strings). In this case, a simple string cannot support font styles.

```
Sub EventControl1_OnUnexpectedWindow(Sender, Window, LogParams)
  LogParams.MessageText = "An unexpected window has appeared."
  ' Specifies the string that will be posted to the Additional Info panel

  LogParams.FontStyle.Bold = True
  LogParams.FontColor = clSilver
  LogParams.Color = clFuchsia
End Sub
```

Here is the complete directory on string manipulation -> [Click Here](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/10308/)

You'll notice that there are no articles on string formatting and colors, that's because a string is a scripting tool, and not an object that can support formatting.